# How to set one candle stick color using mpl_finance?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

from mpl_finance import candlestick_ochl
from matplotlib.dates import num2date
%matplotlib notebook 

# data in a text file, 5 columns: time, opening, close, high, low
# note that I'm using the time you formated into an ordinal float
# data = np.loadtxt('finance-data.txt', delimiter=',')
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
        [2, 3, 1, 5, 1],
        [3, 4, 3, 5, 2.3]
        ])

# determine number of days and create a list of those days
ndays = np.unique(np.trunc(data[:,0]), return_index=True)
xdays =  []
for n in np.arange(len(ndays[0])):
    xdays.append(datetime.date.isoformat(num2date(data[ndays[1],0][n])))

# creation of new data by replacing the time array with equally spaced values.
# this will allow to remove the gap between the days, when plotting the data
data2 = np.hstack([np.arange(data[:,0].size)[:, np.newaxis], data[:,1:]])

# plot the data
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.85, 0.7])
    # customization of the axis
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', width=2, length=8,
               labelsize=12, pad=8)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
    # set the ticks of the x axis only when starting a new day
ax.set_xticks(data2[ndays[1],0])
ax.set_xticklabels(xdays, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

ax.set_ylabel('Quote ($)', size=20)
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])

drawData = candlestick_ochl(ax, data2, width=0.5, colorup='g', colordown='r')
```

and here is the output:

[image]

I would like to change the middle one to orange. How can I find out the tick and change its' color? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most artists in matplotlib have a `.set_color()` method.

```
lines, rectangles = candlestick_ochl(ax, data2, width=0.5, colorup='g', colordown='r')

lines[1].set_color("orange")
rectangles[1].set_color("orange")
```

[image]